# how to set if isset statement below

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a javascript function below where when a file has finished uploading, it will display the neccessary messages:

```
function stopImageUpload(success){

      var imagename = <?php echo json_encode($imagename); ?>;   
      var result = '';
      if (success == 1){
         result = '<span class="msg">The file was uploaded successfully!</span><br/><br/>';
         $('.listImage').append(imagename + '<br/>');
      }
      else {
         result = '<span class="emsg">There was an error during file upload!</span><br/><br/>';
      }

return true;
}
```

Now I am trying to retrieve the $_SESSION variable below and then use the javascript function above (which is on a seperate page) to call the $_SESSION as '$imagename' and then append it into .list.

But my question is how do I write the if issett statement above so it can tell if the $_SESSION variable below is set so then I can use $imagename to retrieve the session?

Below is php script where it contains the $_SESSION and where files are uploaded:

```
    if (isset($_POST['fileImage'])) {
      $_SESSION['imagename'] =  $_FILES['fileImage']['name'];

    if( file_exists("ImageFiles/".$_FILES['fileImage']['name'])) {  
        $_SESSION['fileImage']['name'] = $_FILES['fileImage']['name'];
        $parts = explode(".",$_FILES['fileImage']['name']);
        $ext = array_pop($parts);
        $base = implode(".",$parts);
        $n = 2;

        while( file_exists("ImageFiles/".$base."_".$n.".".$ext)) $n++;
        $_FILES['fileImage']['name'] = $base."_".$n.".".$ext;

        move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileImage"]["tmp_name"], 
        "ImageFiles/" . $_FILES["fileImage"]["name"]);
        $result = 1;


    }
        else
          {
          move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileImage"]["tmp_name"],
          "ImageFiles/" . $_FILES["fileImage"]["name"]);
          $result = 1;

          }
      }


    ?>

    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
window.top.stopImageUpload(<?php echo "'$result'";?>);</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
var imagename = <?php if (isset($_SESSION['imagename'])) echo json_encode($_SESSION['imagename']); ?>;
```

Comment: What if `$SESSION['imagename']` isn't set? `var imagename = ;` You might want to use a ternary to create valid javascript or add an else.

Comment: @PhpMyCoder -- you're right, though I'd go one further in that I don't think it's even necessary to use a session. Given that the OP's code uses `$result` within the code that sets the session, he could pass the filename as another argument for the JavaScript function that's in the other file.